# Reverse Replication working when I freshly add cq:distribute prop

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am trying to demonstrate basic reverse replication on AEM 6.5.10.
Created a new reverse replication agent in author which works fine.

Created a servlet to modify page content which changes some values as well as adds the cq:distribute  property with value true.
Whenever I run the servlet and the page content get the distribute property, reverse replication works. After this If I hit the servlet again then some props change but reverse replication does not work.

When I checked the logs I found that the polling is working fine and it fetched 0 files which means there is nothing in the outbox.

Now here is the weird part -> If I delete the cq:distribute property from crx/de and run the servlet then reverse replication works.
In short: Reverse replication works only when I add the cq:distribute property to the node. If the property already exists and I change some other property then the reverse replication does not work.

Comment: What is the use case for reverse replication?

Comment: @ronnyfm to replicate changes in any pageNode of Publish to author env

Comment: Ok, I got it, it is still a little bit unclear to me, are anonymous users allowed to change data in the pages themselves?

Comment: @ronnyfm I don't think so I just wanted to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Basically we have to add fresh cq:distribute property everytime i need to do reverse replication and remove it afterwards through code.